# Delete multiple lines from text file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have a text file containing 100 lines.
I want to delete first 20 lines from that file
I have a following code

IS anyone tell me how to do that?
this code only deleting 1 line.
I want to delete first 20 lines

```
string line = null;
int line_number = 0;
int line_to_delete = 12;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output")) {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            line_number++;

            if (line_number == line_to_delete)
                continue;

            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im using .net 2.0

Comment: It seems odd that you've written the code like it is if your intent is to delete the first 20 lines. Having written `int line_to_delete = 12;` and then `if (line_number == line_to_delete)` shows that the intent was something else. Is this your code?

Comment: And given this code there are two fairly trivial changes required to make it work. I assume you're a beginner and this isn't your code?

Comment: @Enigmativity : Yes this is not my code. i just want to delete 20 lINES FROM TOP OF THE TEXT FILE. how can i do using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your current code only deletes the line equal to `line_to_delete` To resolve you would just need to change your if statement.

```
if (line_number > 20)  //i would suggest not hardcoding 20
{
    writer.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: You are a genius bro.. Thanks a lot man !

Comment: @haseakash - no just a simple logic error. Glad it helped